# Where do I pose problems pertaining to analysis of binary data?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question lined up to request help for / the solution to a problem. My problem entails 256 pairs of large [< 2^64] numbers and requests that further patters be found. I have done some of the work and have got some of the way there, but not enough. My question can be classified as 'Here's a chunk of organised binary data. Find the patterns / relations please.' or 'Assist me in my special case reverse engineering project.'

Where do I ask this? The data comes from network communications and, correct me if I'm wrong, but [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) looks to be all about reading machine code, decompilation, etc. Asking on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) just didn't seem quite right.

Also, when I do ask, ought I offer a bounty given the nature of my request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in that Reverse Engineering would not be the most appropriate place for your question. Its [on-topic help page](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) makes it clear that the site is just about the reverse engineering of software programs.

I would ask such a question on **[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)**, the statistics/patterns Stack Exchange site. Its [on-topic help page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically allows "mathematical statistics" and (perhaps less relevantly) "data mining." If the question is homework, they have a `self-study` tag.